# How to make sections in Bootstrap different heights, depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been making a website with bootstrap and am trying to use sections to separate parts. However on large screens there is too much space between the text and the end of the section and on small screens the text runs of the section? Each section has a set height in the css which I believe is something to with it.

This is the website I used to create sections so it is similar to mine: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp
Thanks

Comment: Show some code here, what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the min-height to an `absolute` value such as `500px`, you can use a `relative` positioning value like `100vh` which means, it will take the height of the visible window of the browser. To know more about (`vh` and `vw` units) visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units), so the sections will be the exact height as the browser viewport. Please refer the below example.

But sometimes the section height, will be lesser than the text height of the section, causing overflow, inorder to prevent this, we use the property `max-height:fit-content` which will set the height based on the content inside, so we can use this as a fallback when the min height is exceeded and prevent any possibility of text overflow!

```css
html, body {
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;min-height:100vh;max-height:fit-content;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;min-height:100vh;max-height:fit-content;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;min-height:100vh;max-height:fit-content;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;min-height:100vh;max-height:fit-content;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;min-height:100vh;max-height:fit-content;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I do not recommend copy and pasting from w3schools. Their code is very basic and using it could have design flaws depending on your website and your styling.

To fix your issue, you must add the code you are talking about. As an overview of whatever it is, scrollspy does not need height diameters. I suggest removing any height in your styling sheets. Whatever content you have within the specified area you are scrolling, will be the height. If removing the height doesn't work, please post your code so I can answer you with a more direct solution.